# in Python using the multiprocessing module, how can I determine which object caused a PicklingError?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a complex Python program. I'm trying to use the multiprocess Pool to parallelize it. I get the error message

`PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed`.

The traceback shows the statemen `return send(obj)`

My hypothesis is that its the "obj" that is causing the problem and that I need to make it pickle-able.

How can I determine which object is the cause of the problem? The program is complex and simply guessing might take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add some logging right before return send(obj)? At a very minimum, this could help:

```
print repr(obj)
return send(obj)
```

Or, to only print when it results in an error:

```
try:
   return send(obj)
except:
   print '***', repr(obj)
   raise
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing could be caused by passing the wrong kind of function to the multiprocessing.Pool methods. The passed function must be directly importable from its parent module. It cannot be a method of a class, for instance.